# Grammartical questions

Tags: grammar

Is it **in/with**? in this question it says,
The manager was delighted in/with her efficiency.

Another question I'm puzzled at is
Tom and his brother **have/has** been invited to the party.
should we use singular/plural verbs, thank you for helping out.

Comment: Hi and welcome to English Language Stack Exchange. Please note that we require one question per posting. You are asking two things, so there should be two questions. Also, a specific title will be more helpful to other users.

Comment: Oh, I thought it would be bothersome to answer to answers separately but ok sure will do.

Comment: Oh great! You accepted the answer (Alicat202) to the question you've now deleted. P.S Please check the spelling in the title, there's no second R in *grammatical*. Please write a more specific question, 70% of all questions posted on EL&U could be called "grammatical questions" :)

Comment: Please do not edit questions in such a way that it invalidates existing answers. I have reverted your question to its original form so that the answer you accepted actually makes sense.

Comment: I meant to say a more specific *(question) title*.

Comment: I'm truly rendered speechless...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To **delight *in*** something is to  enjoy it, to find great pleasure and joy in it.

> The new parents delighted in their child's first smile.

To **be delighted *with*** something or someone has a more utilitarian connotation; when delighted with something or someone we are more than satisfied with how it or the person performs. We are happy with how it works or how the person is working out.

> The queen was delighted with her new hairdresser.
>
> The student was delighted with his new sound-cancelling headphones.

Answer (score 1):

With regards to the second part of the question, the answer is 'have' because of the plural subject -

*Tom and his brother **have** been invited to the party.*

If the subject is singular -

*Tom **has** been invited to the party.*